# Image of a symmetric law

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Assume I have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ that is mapped by a measurable function $X$ into $(E,\mathcal{E})$, moreover $P(X \in U)=P(-X \in U)$, now $Y$ maps this measurable space into $(G, \mathcal{G})$.

Is it true that: $P(Y(X)  \in V)=P(Y(-X)  \in V)$ or not?

Under which conditions it is.

If we have a continuos Brownian motion $B$ and a stopping time $\tau=\inf\{t: B_t \notin(-1,1)\} $, is it true (and why) that:
$B_{\tau}$ has the same law as $-B_{\tau}$ ?
And how do you compute those laws.

Thanks.

Comment: First part is trivial: $P(Y(X) \in V)=P(X \in Y^{-1}(V)=P(-X \in Y^{-1}(V)P(Y(-X) \in V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall the following:

> Let $X,X':\Omega\to E$ be two random variables and $f:E\to F$ be a
>   measurable map (of course with the same $\sigma$-algebra for $E$).
>
> If $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution, then $f(X)$ and $f(X')$
>   have the same distribution as well.

This property gives you the answer of your two questions.

First of all, if $\mathbb P(X\in U)=\mathbb P(-X\in U)$ for all $U\in\mathcal E$, then $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, so $Y(X)$ and $Y(-X)$ have the same distribution and $\mathbb P(Y(X)\in V)=\mathbb P(Y(-X)\in V)$ for all $V\in\mathcal G$.

Second, let $C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)$ denote the set of continuous functions from $\mathbb R_+$ to $\mathbb R$. Then your brownian motion $B$ is a random variable $B:\Omega\to C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)$, which has the same distribution as $-B$. Let $F:C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ be defined for all $b\in C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)$ by
$$
F(b)=\inf\{t\in\mathbb R_+\mid b(t)\notin(-1,1)\}
$$

Clearly, for all $b\in C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)$, we have $F(b)=F(-b)$. Let $H:C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ be defined for all $b\in C(\mathbb R_+,\mathbb R)$ by
$$
H(b)=b\left(F(b)\right)
$$

Since $B$ and $-B$ have the same distribution, $H(B)=B_{F(B)}$ and $H(-B)=-B_{F(-B)}=-B_{F(B)}$ have the same distribution. Yet $F(B)=\tau$. So $B_\tau$ and $-B_\tau$ have the same distribution.

Moreover, $B_\tau\in\{-1,1\}$ by continuity of the sample paths. Since $B_\tau$ and $-B_\tau$ have the same distribution we have $\mathbb P(B_\tau=1)=\mathbb P(B_\tau=-1)=\frac12$.

Comment: F is measurable?

Comment: You can easily check that $\{F(b)\le t\}=\bigcap_{k\ge1}\bigcup_{s\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb Q_+}\{\vert b(s)\vert\ge1-\frac 1k\}$, hence it is measurable.

Comment: Thank you you've been very helpful and detailed.